# Build for older glibc

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, glibc

I'm building 32 bit c++ library that will run on old system on modern Ubuntu machine. Application works fine on Ubuntu, but when I moved to old Centos 6.9 machine I got error:

```
Failed to open my lib: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/aaa/bbb/libme.so)
```

How to solve this problem? How to build for older glibc?

Comment: Did you try to build it on Centos 6.9?

Comment: Yes, and it runs fine. But I can't develop there since GDB is too old on this system.

Comment: Looks like you don't have GLibc v 3.4.21 on Centos 6.9. Have you tried downgrading gcc to the same version as the one on Centos that works?

Comment: `GLIBCXX_3.4.21` : Not glibc ! ... 'GLIBCXX_3.4.21' is an object in   `libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.21` from gcc version 5.x .

Answer (score 3):

> The only way to tell the compiler and linker to use older symbol
>   versions is by using linker scripts. However, this requires you to
>   specify the version for each and every symbol, which is an undoable
>   task.

You can use [Holy Build Box](https://github.com/phusion/holy-build-box#problem-introduction)

> Holy Build Box solves the glibc symbol problem by providing a
>   tightly-controlled build environment that contains an old version of
>   glibc.

Comment: Thanks! I will also try Holy Build Box, and look if this might be the holy solution.