# CX_Freeze: The executable from Arch Linux doesn't work on Ubuntu 20.04 due to GLIBC incompatibility

Tags: linux, ubuntu, glibc, cx-freeze, archlinux

Arch Linux is on GLIBC version 2.33 : https://archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/glibc/

but Ubuntu 20.04 is on GLIBC 2.31:

```
$/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 --version
GNU C Library (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) stable release version 2.31.
```

So, when I try to run on Ubuntu 20.04 the executable produced by CX_Freeze on my Arch Linux system, I get:

```
./Documents/exe.linux-x86_64-3.8/myapp: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by ./Documents/exe.linux-x86_64-3.8/myappp
./Documents/exe.linux-x86_64-3.8/myapp: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by ./Documents/exe.linux-x86_64-3.8/myapp)
```

How to make an executable from Arch linux which works on older Linux system like Ubuntu 20.04 (in term of GLIBC)?

Comment: What's the question? I see a statement of fact..

Comment: @tehhowch sorry, I've edited

Comment: what research did you do? ex. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856438/how-can-i-link-to-a-specific-glibc-version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49302522/build-for-older-glibc https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032373/linking-against-an-old-version-of-libc-to-provide-greater-application-coverage https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420513/will-a-linux-executable-compiled-on-one-flavor-of-linux-run-on-a-different-one

Comment: @KamilCuk It's interesting (I didn't use the term `linker` in my search but only `cx-freeze` and `glibc` which gets nothing). But it doesn't explain how to do it with CX_Freeze.

Answer (score 0):

> How to make an executable from Arch linux which works on older Linux system like Ubuntu 20.04 (in term of GLIBC)?

Options:

- run Ubuntu 20.04 in a virtualized environment and compile it there (ie. docker), or
- compile glibc 2.31 from sources and install on archlinux and link your application with it, or
- downgrade archlinux to the version with glibc 2.31, or
- link statically with glibc or with other C standard library, or
- copy compiled glibc libraries and distribute it with your application with a custom configuration and some startup script, or
- distribute the whole chroot with archlinux with your application installed (you could use systemd-machine or publish docker image or similar).

TBH just run ubuntu:20.04 in a docker and build your application there. Typically applications are built for each distribution separately anyway.

Comment: `link your application with it` Can you describe how to do it with CX_Freeze?

Comment: No, I cannot. I do not have experience with it.

Comment: cx-freeze-6.6 is in PyPi, can be installed with pip3 : `pip3 install cx-freeze`

Comment: Even more briefly, just do what you already did, but inside an Ubuntu 20.04 container or in another suitably compatible environment. Generally speaking, stuff made on an older system will run fine on a slightly newer system, whereas the opposite cannot be expected.

Comment: `LD_PRELOAD` of newer GLIBC will not work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617

Comment: Right - but, you can do `/path/to/your/ld-linux.so.2 executable` to handle interpreter.

Answer (score -1):

You need to build a glibc from source and put all the libraries in a folder.

For example, for a Ubuntu 20.04 targeted system (which understands only executables compiled with GLIBC_2.31), put in a GLIBC_LIB folder the 5 produced `so` files:

- ld-2.31.so
- ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
- libc.so.6
- libm.so.6
- libpthread.so.0

Then, run CX_Freeze with this:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/GLIBC_LIB python setup.py build
```

Note: you can't link a specific library file, you need to link a folder where the library is.

Comment: This wouldn't work, for reasons explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617